# Using multiple textboxes text to form a JSON string

Tags: c#, json, winforms

I have a button that will store the text value of 80 text boxes in winforms c#.

The button looks something like this at the moment

```
    private void btnSaveChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Create new connection to the MongoDB Database and select the database and "table"
        var nol = NetworkOpsLayer.NetworkOpsLayer.CreateForDirectMongoConnection("mongodb://snipip", "snipdbname", "snip");
        //Inser the document starting with the selected node name, id, timestamp and then the entire loan data
        nol.InsertDoc("{ \"LoanName\" : \"" + tvTodoList.SelectedNode.Name + "\", \"AgentName\" : \"" + txtAgentName.Text + "\" }");
    }
```

This approach will work but I will end up with a string that is very long. `nol.InsertDoc("{long JSON string of keys and textboxIDs}")` as 80 textbox values each with their JSON key will be contained inside the string.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to go about this? Would it be possible to still form a valid JSON string by looping through each textbox on the form and give it a key that relates to the textbox so it's identifiable inside the MongoDB database?

Comment: you can try to make one eventhandler for all textboxes, that store their value (when the text changes) in a dictionary<textbox, string>. with your save button, you can create your JSON with around 10 lines of code (loop over the dictionary)

Comment: If you are concatenating 80 textboxes, then you should use `StringBuilder.Append`  to concatenate your string instead of `+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the controls pick out the names of the textboxes and the corresponding values like this:

```
List<string> textboxNames = new List<string>();
List<string> textboxValues = new List<string>();

foreach (var c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c is TextBox)
    {                   
        textboxNames.Add((c as TextBox).Name);
        textboxValues.Add((c as TextBox).Text);
    }
}
```

What you do with those values is up to you :)